How to access previously created ipynb files under Windows 11
Since 2013 I've been using jupyter notebook or jupyterlab, almost every day, without any problems.
Two days ago I switched from a laptop with Windows 10 and Jupyter Notebook 7.3.1/Jupyterlab 4.3.2 to a laptop with Windows 11 and the same versions of JN and JL. When I launch jupyter notebook I can only access two ipynb files created in "C://Users//myname//Documents".  If I click Documents in Jupyter Notebook its subfolders  are not listed. There are saved the  ipynb files, transferred from the laptop with windows 10. Any attempt to access them, as I did  in  the last 11 years, is unsuccessful.
What's new with Jupyter in Windows 11?  What's the role of upload button from the upper right corner of the notebook? Under windows 10 I never used it.

How do you launch Jupyter Notebooks? Do you have anaconda or VS Code? Did you try "upload"? it should make a copy of the file you choose into the folder where you opened jupyter notebook.

I have an environment within miniconda3. After activation in Anaconda prompt, I used to call jupyter notebook, and either to create a new notebook in a subfolder from Documents or to open an older one. Under windows 11 this approach is no more possible. Searching the web I stumbled upon this similar case, discussed on MS forum:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/document-folder-path-in-windows-11/1e63c53b-9d6e-42be-91c3-4e974b4f1b87.

Starting with a new Windows 11 version, released in 2023, you have a local account on your system and and a permisive one. The latter is your name as a user of Microsoft, while the former consists in the first five letters of your name.  Jupyter Notebook and an IDE for a programming language can open only files saved in a folder created by the "permissive" account, outside the folders Documents, Desktop, that are under the control of the local account.
Hence I created a new folder, Working, and automatically it has been considered as created by the account with my entire name,
and I have access to any ipynb file and can save new ones there.
